# ExtJS 6.5 Treegrid with different model for Parent and Child

Tags: extjs

I am loading a dynamic treegrid with children loading only after expanding the tree column (separate rest call). The parent model is different from the child model other than the shared Key. I am able to do load the parent tree store. I was also able to load and add childnodes to the parent node. When i expand the treecolumn, i only see the shared Key but not the other columns of the childnode. Can the loaded child node have its own model ? Also, is there a way to display the childnode column names in a separate grid-like view ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) showing what you have?

Comment: Turns out rowwidget is really what i needed NOT a tree. I was able to develop the widget i need. Thanks!